# Post route instead of get LARAVEL

Tags: laravel, routes

I want to delete a user in a laravel application (as admin). Therefor I have a route:
`Route::post('/dashboard/{id}/delete', 'Auth\Registercontroller@delete');`

When I click on the delete button, that leads to this link I get this error:
`The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.`
The route I made, is a POST route so I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: How does your button code looks like? (Or the form if there is one).

Comment: ```<a href="dashboard/{{$user->id}}/delete"><img src="imgs/X_mark.svg" class="remove_account" alt="cross" width="15px"></a>```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stay within conventions, this is how I would tackle this. Assuming you are using Blade templates:

```
<form action="/dashboard/{{ $your_id_variable }}" method="POST">
    @method('DELETE')

    @csrf

    <button type="submit">Delete</button>

</form>
```

Then your route type would be `delete` as you have spoofed it be as such in your form:

```
Route::delete('/dashboard/{id}', 'Auth\Registercontroller@destroy');
```

Note that I have changed the controller method to `destroy` as per Laravel convention.

Answer (score 0):

The error happened because it used the route as 'GET' and you have it defined as 'POST'

Modify your Route to look like this:

```
Route::post('/dashboard/{id}/delete', 'Auth\Registercontroller@delete')->name('user.delete');
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault();document.getElementById('user-delete').submit();"> Delete </a>
    <form id="user-delete" action="{{ route('user.delete',$id) }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
        @csrf

    </form>
```